# What is wrong with my LongestMatrixPath ruby algorithm?

Tags: ruby, algorithm, matrix

Using the Ruby language, have the function LongestMatrixPath(strArr) take the array of strings stored in strArr, which will be an NxM matrix of positive single-digit integers, and find the longest increasing path composed of distinct integers. When moving through the matrix, you can only go up, down, left, and right. For example: if strArr is ["345", "326", "221"], then this looks like the following matrix:

3 4 5

3 2 6

2 2 1

For the input above, the longest increasing path goes from: 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> 6. Your program should return the number of connections in the longest path, so therefore for this input your program should return 3. There may not necessarily always be a longest path within the matrix.

```
    def recursiveFunction(array, row, col, path)
      current = array[row][col]
      row-1 >= 0  ? up = array[row-1][col] : up = nil 
      row+1 < array.length ? down = array[row+1][col] : down = nil 
      col-1 >= 0 ? left = array[row][col-1] : left = nil 
      col+1 < array[row].length ? right = array[row][col+1] : right = 
      nil 

      if !path.include?(current) && current.to_i > path[-1].to_i 
        path.push(current) 
        p path 
        if up && up.to_i > current.to_i 
          recursiveFunction(array, (row-1), col, path)
        elsif down && down.to_i > current.to_i 
          recursiveFunction(array, (row+1), col, path)
        elsif left && left.to_i > current.to_i 
          recursiveFunction(array, row, (col-1), path)
        elsif right && right.to_i > current.to_i 
          recursiveFunction(array, row, (col+1), path)
        end
      end 

      path 
    end

    def LongestMatrixPath(strArr)
      # turn each string into an array
      strArr.map!{|str| str.split("")}

      # calculate up, down, left, right formula
      # up = [-1][same]
      # down = [+2][same]
      # left = [same][-1] 
      # right = [same][+1]

      # create data structure to store paths
      path = []

      # create loop that loops through each element in each array 
      inside strArr
      # then apply recursive function to each element
      longest_path = 0
      row = 0
      while row < strArr.length 
        col = 0 
        while col < strArr[row].length  
          result = recursiveFunction(strArr, row, col, path=[])
          longest_path = result.length if result.length > longest_path 
          col += 1
        end
        row += 1 
      end

      # return number of connections 
      result.length-1    
    end


    # LongestMatrixPath(["345", "326", "221"]) 
    # correct answer: 3, my answer: 3

    # LongestMatrixPath(["12256", "56219", "43215"])
    # correct answer: 4, my answer: 3

    # LongestMatrixPath(["67", "21", "45"]) 
    # correct answer: 3, my answer: 1

    # LongestMatrixPath(["111", "111", "111"]) 
    # correct answer: 0, my answer: 0

    # LongestMatrixPath(["123", "456", "789"]) 
    # correct answer: 4, my answer: 4
```

Comment: The portion of code you posted is too long. Pinpoint the crucial part.

Comment: the crucial part is the recursive function at the top

Answer (score 0):

The problem exists in this fragment:

```
    if up && up.to_i > current.to_i 
      recursiveFunction(array, (row-1), col, path)
    elsif down && down.to_i > current.to_i 
      recursiveFunction(array, (row+1), col, path)
    elsif left && left.to_i > current.to_i 
      recursiveFunction(array, row, (col-1), path)
    elsif right && right.to_i > current.to_i 
      recursiveFunction(array, row, (col+1), path)
    end
```

Here, if `up` is larger than `current` and, for example, `left` is also larger than `current`, you only go up (because of `elsif`). Instead, you need to go in all possible directions and choose most "promising" one. I altered your code a bit to achieve that, trying to change as little as possible. This works, but might not be the best option though.

```
    def recursiveFunction(array, row, col, original_path)
        current = array[row][col]
        row-1 >= 0  ? up = array[row-1][col] : up = nil 
        row+1 < array.length ? down = array[row+1][col] : down = nil 
        col-1 >= 0 ? left = array[row][col-1] : left = nil 
        col+1 < array[row].length ? right = array[row][col+1] : right = 
        nil 

        path = original_path.dup
        if !path.include?(current) && current.to_i > path[-1].to_i 
        path.push(current)
        # p path
        options = []
        if up && up.to_i > current.to_i 
            options << recursiveFunction(array, (row-1), col, path)
        end
        if down && down.to_i > current.to_i 
            options << recursiveFunction(array, (row+1), col, path)
        end
        if left && left.to_i > current.to_i 
            options << recursiveFunction(array, row, (col-1), path)
        end
        if right && right.to_i > current.to_i 
            options << recursiveFunction(array, row, (col+1), path)
        end

        best_path = options.sort_by{ |p| p.length }.last
        path += best_path.drop(path.length) if best_path
        end

        path 
    end
```

Not a couple of thing here:

1. Instead modifying `path` parameter given into function, it gets duplicated, so you can work on it in many steps.
2. All conditions for `up`, `down`, `left` and `right` are checked now. The results are put into an array and then the best result (in terms of length) is chosen.
3. Then the remainder of this longest path is appended to `path` with `path += best_path.drop(path.length)` (if exists)

The results for examples you gave are correct, except example two, where correct answer is 5, not 4.

There is much more that can be improved in this code though. For example, you can do `strArr.map!{|str| str.split("").map(&:to_i)}` and get rid of all those `.to_i` in the code.